# Possible to remotely update Windows 10 IOT Core App without Azure or Windows Store?

Tags: azure, windows-10-iot-core, app-update

I am in the process of finishing up a Windows 10 IOT Core app to be deployed on Raspberry Pi 3 devices for a single location beta test. The app is consumer facing and reads from a sensor so I am sure there are going to be at least 1 or 2 updates per week as we perfect the app. Everything I am reading says you can only achieve app updates from Windows Device Portal, Windows Store, or Azure.

1. Windows Device Portal works fine for local management/deployment right now but won't work remotely because the devices will eventually be installed all throughout the country behind different firewalls, etc. We don't want to have to keep up with customer firewall port forwarding.
2. Windows Store probably won't work because we don't want to have to wait for up to 48 hours for update approvals. Also not sure if Windows 10 IOT fully supports Windows Store yet.
3. I have not figured out how Azure IOT Hub manages app updates but I would really like to avoid having to use Azure if possible since we prefer to keep everything on our own servers and not pay cloud providers for stuff we can do on our own servers.

Has anyone figure out how to run a background service to download an app update and apply it?

I am just going to have to deal with Azure IOT Hub?

Answer (score 1):

There is another option: **[Using OMA-DM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps#using-oma-dm)**.

> Using OMA-DM: The app is updated using an OMA-DM compliant device
>   management channel such as Intune or System Center Configuration
>   Manager (SCCM)
>
> The OMA-DM interface is supported in Windows 10 IoT Core and any
>   OMA-DM compliant management solution can be used to install and update
>   applications. Read the documentation for [EnterpriseModernAppManagement
>   CSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/client-management/mdm/enterprisemodernappmanagement-csp) for usage instructions.

**NOTE: Some information of EnterpriseModernAppManagement CSP relates to prereleased product which may be substantially modified before it's commercially released.**

Answer (score 0):

You do need a type of (online/internet) service to connect to your IoT Core devices. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps):

1. Microsoft Store: The app is published and updated from the Microsoft Store
2. Using Component Update Service: The app is published to Windows Update and updated like any other OEM package (driver package) **Coming soon**
3. Using Azure IoT Device Management: The app is published to Azure Storage and updated through the Azure DM channel New for Windows 10, version 1709
4. Using OMA-DM: The app is updated using an OMA-DM compliant device management channel such as Intune or System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM)

With Store, you'll be using the Microsoft Store service; Azure IoT Device Management will be using Azure IoT hub; OMA-DM can use Intune/SCCM or *your own infrastructure ([OMA-DM Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/server-requirements-windows-mdm))*